# ngSemantic with angular error - unexpected module NgSemanticModule

Tags: angular

I have an error while building my angular app using `ng build -–prod`

[ngSemanticModule error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl5BH.png)

**He’s how I installed the module**

```
npm install ng-semantic --save

npm install jquery --save
```

my angular-cli.json file

```
  "styles": [
    "../semantic/dist/semantic.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../semantic/dist/semantic.js"
  ]
```

my app.module.ts

```
import { NgSemanticModule } from "ng-semantic";

...

  imports: [
    NgSemanticModule
    ...
]
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "someproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.1.13",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**My attempts at fixing the error**

Added following lines to ng-semantic.d.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

...

@NgModule({
        declarations: [
                NgSemanticModule
        ]
})
export declare class NgSemanticModule {
}
```

Tried using this line in appmodule

```
import { NgSemanticModule } from "ng-semantic/ng-semantic";
```

Also followed this post

https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic/issues/105

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue using in **ng-semantic.d.ts** file:

```
@NgModule()
export declare class NgSemanticModule {
}
```

Instead:

```
@NgModule({
        declarations: [
                NgSemanticModule
        ]
})
export declare class NgSemanticModule {
}
```